# How are properties defined on React elements using JSX 'collected' into a single object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In this React code:

```
const App = ({val}) => {
  console.log(val) // logs 20 to console
  return <div>val</div>
}

<App val={20} val2={1}/>
```

I understand that the argument passed to the `App` function is a kind of 'implicit' destructuring. i.e. where I use `App` (via JSX) I annotate to properties: `val`, `val2`. These properties are ***collected*** into a an object: `{val: 20, val2: 1}`, and so the JSX results in JavaScript that looks like this:

```
App({val: 20, val2: 1})
```

Then in the argument of `App`, I'm effectively destructuring like so:

```
const {val} = {val: 20, val2: 1}
```

So it seems in the conversion from the JSX `<App val={20} val2={1}>` that there is the 'opposite' of destructuring occurring. Is this correct?

Does the process by which this occurs make use of the 'rest' operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, it's done by JSX parser, one of the parser implementations would be https://github.com/RReverser/acorn-jsx.

Example of the process would be something like,

- Looking through JSX code, line by line;
- Identifying React elements, according to specs (see below);
- For each element, will be parse their attributes, and values. And pushing them into `attributes` array. Which later would be `props` object for `React.createElement`.

Specification describing JSX syntax you can find here https://github.com/facebook/jsx.

Answer (score 2):

[JSX syntax](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html) is syntactic sugar for `React.createElement`, [JSX props](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#props-in-jsx) are syntactic sugar for `React.createElement` props argument, which is an object.

```
<App val={20} val2={1}/>
```

is syntactic sugar for

```
React.createElement(App, { val: 20, val2: 1 });
```

For the rest of the props, [spread attributes](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#spread-attributes) are applicable, they are syntactic sugar for object spread syntax.

```
<App val={20} val2={1} {...rest}/>
```

is syntactic sugar for ES2018

```
React.createElement(App, { val: 20, val2: 1, ...rest });
```

or ES6

```
React.createElement(App, Object.assign({ val: 20, val2: 1}, rest));
```

Comment: The JSX syntactic sugar requires a preprocessing step to create `React.createElement`. What I guess I'm asking is whether there is a way to 'collect' variables defined by const into a single object: const a = 2, b = 3, c etc. and then pass them as a single object with those keys. I'm guessing not now that I'm writing this out (I'm still a little uncertain around rest/spread/destructuring - sorry if this is a poor question)

Comment: This is what `rest` object above shows. It would be `const props = { a: 2, b: 3}; <App {...props}/>`, I guess. Is this what you ask about?